# How to achieve Custom Paging in SQL Pivot Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure accepts date and month as parameter that results monthly attendance sheet. In order to achieve Paging function, a parameter called 'PageNo' which contain page index. I haveto show results based on page No.

**Stored Procedure**

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sps_AttendanceShowModified] @mon int, @year
int,@pageNo int As begin DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)=''; DECLARE
@query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='';

set @query =  'SELECT * from  (
     select  e.Name,a.WorkHours,DAY(a.AttendaceDate) AS d1 from  Attendace a,employee e where e.EmpID=a.EmpID and
MONTH(a.AttendaceDate)= ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @mon)+ ' AND
YEAR(a.AttendaceDate)= ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @year)+ ' ) src pivot 
(
    max(WorkHours) for d1 in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30])
 ) piv'

execute(@query) end
```

Comment: I assume you didn't mean to tag mysql?

Comment: Or mysqli. This is clearly SQL Server based on the use of the `dbo` schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you could amend your code to use OFFSET like this:

```
DECLARE @pageSize INT;
DECLARE @pageNumber INT;

SET @pageSize = 1000;
SET @pageNumber = 1;

SELECT my_columns_here
FROM dbo.my_table_here
ORDER BY my_ordered_column 
OFFSET @pageSize * (@pageNumber - 1) ROWS 
FETCH NEXT @pageSize ROWS ONLY;
```

On a separate note, I noticed you are using a classic JOIN:

```
SELECT blabla
FROM Attendace a, employee e
WHERE e.EmpID = a.EmpID
```

Most developers and dba's will use ANSI-92 as a standard these days:

```
SELECT blabla
FROM Attendace        a
  INNER JOIN employee e ON a.EmpID = e.EmpID
```

This way you tend to avoid accidental CROSS joins and unnecessary ambiguity by separating relation from filter logic.